# "Array" command in SAS to manipulate data

Tags: sas

I've the following the data structure

ID Y xx11 xx12 xx13 xx14 xx21   xx22    xx23    xx24    xx31    xx32    xx33    xx34 xx41 xx42  xx43    xx44;

Where Y is the response variable and x's are the covariates.

- xx11    xx12    xx13 xx14 are four repeated measures for group 1.
- xx21    xx22    xx23    xx24 are four repeated measures for group 2.
- xx31 xx32    xx33    xx34 are four repeated measures for group 3.
- xx41 xx42    xx43    xx44 are four repeated measures for group 4.

I need to manipulate the data using "Array" command in SAS to produce the following data set:

ID Y Time Group

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data want;
set have;
array xx xx11--xx44;
do _t = 1 to dim(xx);
  x=xx[_t];
  group = substr(vname(xx[_t]),3,1);
  time = substr(vname(xx[_t]),4,1);
  output;
end;
run;
```

This depends on xx11 through xx44 being consecutive variables (not in any particular order).

Comment: there is one thing i've just noticed/wanted. I wanted to create a time variable the goes from 1 to 4, but in the code, after obtaining the outputs, _t goes from 1 to 16... so basically i want to include the following in the output: ID Y X Time Group. I hope this is not a hard thing to do. THANKS!

Comment: If I understand you right (group=3rd char, time=4th char in variable name, x=original variable value) then I made the change in an edit.